Problem in writing and reading files from MIPS
I am learning to use MIPS for my study. I have a homework that writing a program to read and write the output from .txt file (just like fstream in c++). Yet, when I run the program, it does not return anything. Do you have some suggestions for me in this problem? Thank you very much.
.data
   filename: .asciiz "example.txt"
   buffer: .space 1024
   
.text
.globl main

main: 
     # Open a file
     li $v0, 13   # syscall 13: open file
     la $a0, filename
     li $a1, 0    # Open file for reading
     li $a2, 0
     syscall
     move $s0, $v0 # Save the file descriptor
     
     # Read from file
     li $v0, 14   # syscall 14: read file
     move $a0, $s0
     la $a1, buffer
     li $a2, 1024
     syscall
     
     # Print the buffer to the terminal
     li $v0, 4    # syscall 4: print string
     la $a0, buffer
     syscall
     
     # Close the file
     li $v0, 16   # syscall 16: close file
     move $a0, $s0
     syscall
     
     # Exit
     li $v0, 10   # syscall 10: exit
     syscall


So what I have done is that I use syscall 4 for the output, yet, like I said, it does not work well.

Maybe the open syscall failed ? What is the value of $v0 after that syscall?

What simulator are you running this in?  Hopefully MARS or SPIM, since those system-call numbers look like MARS/SPIM, not for example Linux MIPS.  MARS and QtSPIM both have built-in debuggers that will let you single-step so you can check the return value of each system call.

If you write a program that creates a file with a unique name, like abc123.txt, you can then search your filesystem to find out what directory paths are relative to.  Maybe it's not the same directory as the source, if that's where you put your example.txt.  There might also be some OS-specific permission stuff, e.g. macOS see How to open a saved .asm file in MARS on MacOS (except that also affects MARS opening .asm source files, not just the simulated guest MIPS programs).

I use MARS for running this code and $v0 after first execution is 0x3

Ok, that's what you'd expect from success, 3 is the next fd after stdin stdout and stderr, and it would be negative if there was an error.  (The original MARS docs are offline, but https://eclass.hmu.gr/modules/document/file.php/TP284/%CE%95%CF%81%CE%B3%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AE%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%BF%20%28%CE%9F%CE%BC%CE%AC%CE%B4%CE%B5%CF%82%203%2C%204%2C%205%29/%CE%95%CF%81%CE%B3%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AE%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%BF%203/MIPS%20syscall%20functions.pdf is a PDF copy.)  syscall 14 also returns a value (byte count, or negative for error) so you can check that and memory contents.

Anyway, this code looks like it should work, assuming there's a non-empty example.txt containing ASCII characters.  Even if the file size is >= 1024 so you fill the whole buffer with non-0 bytes, there should be a zero byte after it before the end of the page for v0=4/syscall to find as the terminator for the implicit-length string.  (It would be better to make the buffer size 1025, or the read size 1023, though.  Or put a separate .byte 0 after it.)

Thank you very much for all your help, I think I know the reason is that my program and txt file are in the same directory, yet my MARS is in the different one so it cannot work properly.

You could probably use absolute paths.  If you're on Windows, you probably have to use "foo\\bar"  since quoted strings process C-style escapes, or use forward slashes like c:/foo/bar.  Did an earlier version of your program create an example.txt in the MARS directory or something, and that's why you can now open it for reading?  On Linux and other sensible OSes, running a program like java -jar ~/src/Mars4_5.jar starts it with CWD = wherever I was cded to when I ran Java, so that's the directory that paths are relative to.  Your program works for me on my Linux desktop.
